# How to use external API SDK with Angular4/5

Tags: angular, moltin

I want to use [Moltin](https://moltin.com/) for a project but their SDK requires the use of async wait which isn't really used in Angular4/5 my question is how can I make use of the SDK without having to use global functions as this is considered bad practice.

```
async getCustomerOrders() {
  var customer = await Moltin.Customers.Token("ron@swanson.com", "mysecretpassword");
  await Moltin.Orders.All(customer.token);
}
```

Comment: Why not `Promise.resolve(Moltin.Customers <...>).then(_ => Moltin.Orders.All(_.token))` ?

Comment: Why even bother with the Javascript SDK? I would just create your own Angular services that call the REST api endpoints. Inject those services into your components and off you go.

Comment: @popStar Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: There are two Promises, so you can chain them -`Promise.resolve(Moltin.Customers.Token("ron@swanson.com", "mysecretpassword")).then(customer => Moltin.Orders.All(customer.token))`